# Synchronizing session scoped managed bean

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have 2 screens in my JSF 2.0 application. Screen 1 searches for students and lists students in a table. The student name in the results table is a link to the student details page (screen 2).

My managed bean:

```
@SessionScoped
public class TestController {
private Student studentOnUI; // Student being viewed on the UI 
// synchronized public getters and setters
public String viewStudentAction(String studentId) {
    this.studentOnUI = getStudentFromDB( studentId );   
    return "studentDetailedPage";
}
public synchronized String clearSearchAction() {
    this.studentOnUI = null;
    return "studentSearchPage";
}
```

screen 1 xhtml snippet

```
<!-- search fields -->
<h:commandButton  
    value="Clear Search"
    action="#{testController.clearSearchAction()}"/>
<!-- Search button -->
<!-- search results table -->
```

Screen 2 xhtml snippet

```
<h:outputText value="#{testController.studentOnUI.name}" />
<h:dataTable 
  value="#{testController.studentOnUI.subjects}"
  var="subject">
  <h:outputText value="#{subject.score}"/>
</h:dataTable>
```

I face the following issue:

1. After running search, user clicks on
   a student name (to move into screen
   2)
2. When the render response phase of
   screen 2 is in progress (which has
   EL references to
   testController.studentOnUI), He
   clicks on clear button (without waiting for the first request to complete). Now the
   thread handling the clear request
   sets testController.studentOnUI to null and
   the first thread that is in render
   response phase throws
   NullPointerException when it
   evaluates

   ## {testController.studentOnUI.*}.

Although the managed bean handles synchronization (correctly?) it does not solve the concurrency issue here because, the following could happen

1. Thread 1 (handling request to navigate to screen 2) - evaluates #{testController.studentOnUI.name} and happily renders the value. And then exits the testController.getStudentOnUI() synchronized method. So thread 1 no longer has the lock on the controller instance (in session scope). context switch happens.
2. Thread 2 (handling request to clear
   search results) - does
   testController.studentOnUI = null in
   clearSearchAction(). context switch
   happens.
3. Thread 1 - evaluates the next EL in the page (#{testController.studentOnUI.subjects}) and throws a NullPointerException (as testController.studentOnUI is now null).

Appreciate any pointers on what I am doing wrong with this approach or if a different approach needs to be adopted here.

Comment: what's a screen? you use 2 tabs in the browser? or is it more like a wizard?

Comment: By screen I meant a page. There are no tabs or wizards. The user clicks link 1 on page 1 (in the student table to navigate to the student detailed page) and before the response is complete, clicks on link 2 on page 1.

Answer (score 0):

this is really strange behaviour but then i would rather disable the link on the first page with JavaScript to make it "unclickable".
try with jQuery:

1 button: $('#button').attr("disabled", true);

2 link: $('a.something').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });

I'm not sure about the synchronization in the backing bean since the JSF Controller has to put the lock on your Student object, not the clear method. Am I wrong?